# Saving belongsTo models Cakephp

Tags: cakephp

I have the following model associations:

```
Question belongsTo Category
Category hasMany Question
Question hasMany Answer
Answer belongsTo Question
```

I want to be able to create a new category when creating a Question, but I am getting a `Category.id` validation error, even though I am not sending setting the `Category.id` in the `$this->data` array.  I successfully create new answers in the same form, but the Category is not being created.

My form:

```
<h3>Create multiple choice question</h3>
<?php

echo $this->Form->create('Question', array('action' => 'addmc'));
echo $this->Form->input('Question.name');
echo $this->Form->input('Question.questiontext', array('label' => 'Question Text (What students will see)'));
echo $this->Form->input('Question.generalfeedback', array('label' => 'General feedback (Feedback student will see when reviewing question)'));

for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    echo $this->Form->input('Answer.'.$i.'.answer', array('label' => 'Answer ' . ($i+1)));
    echo $this->Form->input('Answer.'.$i.'.score', array('label' => 'Score (Number from 0 to 100)'));
}
echo $this->Form->input('Category.0.name', array('label' => 'Category'));
echo $this->Form->button('Save question', array('class' => 'form'));
echo $this->Form->end();

?>
```

I am using saveAll in the controller. I tried by removing the validation rule for the `Category.id`. The save operation went through but the category was not created.

Comment: Check you don't have `'required' => true` on your `Category.id` validation rule.

Comment: yeap.. set to false... and the rule is just numeric

Comment: I was thinking that maybe I can only create hasMany models, but not belongsTo models, but I'm not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the controller, you need to save the category first, get that inserted id and assign to category_id in the question, then you can use saveAll on the question and answers.

Answer (score 0):

If Question belongsTo Category, you probably have a Question.category_id field... That one should be used for chosing the category in a select box (at least, that's how I think you want it to work). The way you are trying to achieve this now doesn't make sense to Cake.

Comment: Well that field is not in my form. But I was thinking the same thing... because of the relationship category has to be chosen and not created... But is there any way of going around this?

Comment: I misread what you're trying to do... Also a nice feature would be a normal select (category_id) that contains all current categories and a Ajax operated input through which you can add categories on the fly, don't forget to update the select after the Ajax request so that it contains the new category.